# How to filter items from list using wildcard character?

Tags: c#, list, filtering

I have created a code to process data from one server to another server and it is executing on every few minutes. So, it must be faster. In that process have a list containing more than 1000 records. the records are in string format. I want to filter that records with given part of the string. All matched record should be filtered and stored in another list.

For example: I have some records in the list.

```
Table1_Field1
Table1_Field2
Table1_Field3
Table2_Field4
Table2_Field4
Table2_Field4
```

Supposed if i want to get all record which is containing string part "Table1" then the result should be look like this.

```
Table1_Field1
Table1_Field2
Table1_Field3
```

**I know this can be done by using LINQ. But, I am using Visual Studio 2005 .Net Framework 2.0.** Also I can do that by DataTable.Select() but it is time consuming. Any method consuming time more than 50 millisecond causes the issue in my application. So, It must be faster. I cannot filter record using simple loop with wildcard character '*'.

Please suggest how do i do this in minimum time.

Comment: What kind of List?  A `List<T>` of something?  you want to filter the data source?  1000 string records should EASILY be filterable in 50ms.  As for not being able to do it in a loop, no matter what method you choose, it's going to loop.  LINQ is a shortcut, but you're still going to end up iterating/enumerating each record.  If you're talking about then displaying the filtered records, perhaps THAT is what is time consuming.  Either way, I think we need more information.

Comment: @EliGassert I am very confused to use list object. Should i use an string array or use List<string> or any other collection object. My question is which method is best to get filtered record in minimum time. the type of data is a list of string.

Comment: Can I use BinarySearch in Array?

Comment: If your data is not sorted, then you're limited with what you can do.  If your wildcard is always at the beginning, i.e. `StartsWith` then you can probably SLIGHTLY optimize the search.  However, honestly 1000 data items in a `List<string>` should be VERY fast.  You could create a search/wildcard regex and then iterate your loop and store in a new `List<string>` the results that match.  I'd imagine it'd be quite fast.

Comment: My data has sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @KillerR I dont want to get a part of the string i want list of filtered items from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a List and you want only record which is containing string part "Table1".

The code below will return a List with the results:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("Table1_Field1");
myList.Add("Table1_Field2");
myList.Add("Table1_Field3");
myList.Add("Table2_Field4");
myList.Add("Table2_Field4");
myList.Add("Table2_Field4");

List<string> resultList = myList.FindAll(MyFunc);


private static bool MyFunc(string s)
{

    // AndAlso prevents evaluation of the second Boolean
    // expression if the string is so short that an error
    // would occur.
    if (s.Contains("Table1")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thanks